# Pictures uploaded using blueimp file upload control are black when being viewed after upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I'm using blueimp file upload control in a .NET C# 4.0 web application to upload multiple pictures.

There are several different external users that use different devices, cell phone, point and shoot, or DSLR cameras to take pictures.  After they upload the pictures I take a look at them and several of the pictures from different sources are black.  The filesizes are all > 0 and the resolution of the image is 640 x 480 (or 480 x 640 depending on orientation).  It's consistent only in that they are coming from the same people, but the device they are using is not a factor.  Meaning, if I have 3 people that I'm seeing the black images from, one might be using an iPhone, another a point and shoot, and the 3rd any other device.

I am using the re-size functionality and setting the imageMaxWidth and imageMaxHeight to 640.  I'm also using the imageQuality property.  I've tried setting it at 0.5, 0.8, and 1.0 with no change.

One thing I have noticed is that the thumbnails all appear correctly which makes me think there is something with the resizing code.

FileUpload.aspx

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>

    <title>File Upload</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/load-image.all.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/canvas-to-blob.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload-process.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.fileupload-image.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/uploader.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery.fileupload.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/jquery.fileupload-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <div class="container">

            <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
                <span>Select files...</span>

                <input id="file_upload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple="multiple" />
            </span>

            <div id="progress" class="progress">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="file-upload-progress"></div>

            <label class="message">Press 'Select Files' or Drag your files here to begin uploading.</label>
            <label class="totalfiles"></label>
        </div>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var url = '/ImageUploadHandler.ashx';

            $('#file_upload').fileupload({
                url: url,
                dropZone: $('.container'),
                disableImageResize: false,
                imageMaxWidth: 640,
                imageMaxHeight: 640,
                imageQuality: 0.5,
                imageCrop: false,
                done: function (e, data) {
                    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
                        filecounter++;

                        $('.message').text('File upload in progress, please do not close this window...').show();
                        $('.totalfiles').text(filecounter + ' upload completed').show();

                        var progress = Math.floor(filecounter / totalfiles * 100);
                        $('.progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');

                        if (totalfiles == filecounter) {
                            $('.message').text('File upload complete.');
                            filecounter = 0;
                            totalfiles = 0;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
                totalfiles++;

                $('.message').text('');
                $('.totalfiles').text('');
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are they fully black or some portion of them are black?

Comment: When the pictures come through black, they are all black and the same file size.  We've noticed that the thumbnails will be visible in windows explorer for a second until they all are loaded then they are black.  It's a rare occurrence.  99% of the time the pictures come through just fine.  When they are black all of the pictures from that single source are black.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer about this issue? Are you able to reproduce this ?